# QT QStandardItemModel - how to store a list of items in one cell

Tags: qt, qstandarditemmodel

I am new with QT, so I'll apprciate any help.

In my application, I'm creating a QStandardItemModel with rows and columns. Now I want to save in one cell a list of QStrings - but I dont know how to do that.
I've tried to write this code:

```
    QStandardItem* dataRecords = new QStandardItem();
    QList<QStandardItem* > list;

    QList<QString>::const_iterator dataRecord;
    for( dataRecord = i.value()->begin(); dataRecord != i.value()->end(); ++dataRecord )
        list << new QStandardItem((*dataRecord));

    dataRecords->appendRows(list);
    model->setItem(row, 3, dataRecords);
```

i is a QList of QString.
Now, I dont know how can I access abd retrive the QString values from the model.
Can anyone please help me? or suggest me another way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should read some docks about Model\View proggramming in Qt

To access data stored in model you should use: 
`QVariant QStandardItemModel::data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole )`
To get QModelIndex for particular cell use:
 `QModelIndex QStandardItemModel::index ( int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex() )`
Some code example...

```
QModelIndex superIndex = model->index(i,j);
QString superData= model->data(superIndex).toString();
```